# ssrs pass forms credentials to ssas

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, sql-server-2012

I want to create web service with forms authentication in SSRS and then use it to view reports retrieving data from SSAS cube. Is it possible to, after successfull logon, pass identical user's forms authentication credentials, to SSAS server so with one credentials user is authenticated in two servers? If yes, how I can achieve this task?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

No, because SSAS doesn't alow any form of autentication other than windows authentication. You can definetly connect to SSRS using forms (and by forms I mean a SQL Server user) but then, from SSRS on, you must use a AD user on your SSRS data source to connect to SSAS.

Comment: By forms i meant sth like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902691%28v=sql.80%29.aspx so i would like to use users stored on my own server. And is it possible to pass this user/pass credendtials to SSAS considering i have the same user/pass data on my AD?

Comment: no you cant, SSAS only accepts windows authentication. If you try to connect to a SSAS instance using SSMS you will see that the option to inform user and password is disabled